# Want to save all values of checkbox in csv (php), unfortunately only one gets saved

Tags: php, forms, csv, checkbox, export-to-csv

I have a form and I am exporting the answers into a csv file. Radio buttons working fine. The value of the textarea is not getting exported and the value of all selected checkboxes is also not exported. Only one value gets exported. What I am doing wrong? Please help!

My code index.php

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    include 'php/create-csv.php';
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="" name="contactform">
    <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control control-checkbox"> Insurances            
      <input type="checkbox" value="insurances" name="topic[]"/>
      <div class="control_indicator"></div>
     </label>
     <label class="control control-checkbox"> Savings
      <input type="checkbox"  value="savings" name="topic[]"/>
      <div class="control_indicator"></div>
     </label>
     <label class="control control-checkbox"> Other
      <input type="checkbox" value="other_topic" name="topic[]"/>
      <div class="control_indicator"></div>            
     </label>
     <div id="textarea">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="40"  name="other"></textarea>
      </div>
     </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit" 
    class="submit-btn">
     <?php
       if (isset($errors)) {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
          echo $error;
        }
       }      
      ?>
   </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Code for create-csv.php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $topic = isset($_POST['topic']) ? $_POST['topic'] : '';
   $rating = isset($_POST['rating']) ? $_POST['rating'] : '';
   $other = isset($_POST['other']) ? $_POST['other'] : '';

    if ($rating == '') {
        $errors[] = '<div class="notification error clearfix"><p>Please select a number.</p></div>';
    }
    if ($topic == '') {
     $errors[] = '<div class="notification error clearfix"><p>Please select at 
          least one topic.</p></div>';
    }  
    if (!isset($errors)) {

        if(!empty($_POST['topic'])) {    
            foreach($_POST['topic'] as $value){  
                echo $value; 
            }
        }

        $header = "Rating,Topics,Other\n";

        $data = "$rating, $topic, $other\n";
    $fileName = dirname(__DIR__) . "/results.csv";



            if (file_exists($fileName)) {

                file_put_contents($fileName, $data, FILE_APPEND);
            } else {

                file_put_contents($fileName, $header . $data);
            } 
             header("Location: thankyou.html");
            exit;


        }
    }
```

Comment: *Only one value gets exported* what value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no "rating" in this form you posted. Maybe it is the radio button you mentioned before.

Also, it seems like you're trying to convert an array to string here:

```
$data = "$rating, $topic, $other\n";
```

I recommend you to implode your array with a pipe (|), like this:

```
$data = "$rating, " . implode ("|", $topic) . ", $other\n";
```

Comment: thanks for your promt reply. this helped me!!!
Do you know if there is a way to add the value of the textarea to the column of the topic?

Comment: Of course! If you need $other to be in the same column as $topic, then before assigning the value of $data, add $other as a new index to the $topic array: this way -> $topic[] = $other. Watch out for the line breaks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating

```
    if(!empty($_POST['topic'])) {    
        foreach($_POST['topic'] as $value){  
            echo $value; 
        }
    }
```

To

```
    if(!empty($_POST['topic'])) {    
        foreach($_POST['topic'] as $value){  
            $topic .= ', '.$value; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Regarding your code, I tried it out but unfortunately I get now an empty value.